# Get elements with class starting with "foo" and attach event to them

Tags: mootools

I want to find elements with class starting with foo and attach event listeners to them.

This apparently worked `$$('li[class^=foo]')` but only if `foo` was the first class of the element. So I went for `$$('li').hasClass([class^=foo]);`.

That worked but now I wanted to use ...`class^=foo]).addEvent(...` and that didn't work.
`Object [object Array] has no method 'addEvent'` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxPpk/)

Tried also

```
$$('li').hasClass([class^=foo]).each(function (el) {  
    el.addEvent('mouseenter', function () {
    //...
```

But no sucess - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxPpk/1/)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. several things you could do.

```
var li_elms = $$('li[class*=foo]');
```

will work fine but it will also include `blahfoo`

you can filter:

```
var li_elms = $$('li').filter(function(el){ 
    return el.get('class').indexOf('foo') !== -1; 
});
```

you can also delegate the event to the parent ul and check if the matching el should be considered at the time of firing.

Comment: Thank you for checking my question! `.filter()` was also a good idea. Anyway, I can get the "right" object array with `.hasClass([class^=foo])`. The problem is I cannot `addEvent` to the elements. I thought about `.each()` but got error -> jsfiddle.net/PxPpk/1

Comment: you can add the event. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/PxPpk/2/ works. you could not add the event on the `.hasClass` because the mootools iterator will do a `.map` for you and return an array like this: `[true, true, true, false]` since you chain it onto the collection.